# Using vector::data() chaining with member function print differnet values as pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++

I have a class `hello` with a method which returns a `vector` member.

I am trying to print out values using `vector::data()` with pointer arithmetic, but I am facing an undefined behavior. See example below:

```cpp
class hello
{
public:
    std::vector<int> data()
    {
        return v;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    hello h;

    std::cout << "----------------------------" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        std::cout << &*(h.data().data() + i) << std::endl;
        std::cout << *(h.data().data() + i) << std::endl;
    }

    int *sa = h.data().data();
    std::cout << "----------------------------" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

        std::cout << sa + i << std::endl;
        std::cout << *(sa + i) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
----------------------------
0x9e2ee0
1
0x9e2ee4
2
0x9e2ee8
3
0x9e2eec
4
----------------------------
0x9e2ee0
0
0x9e2ee4
0
0x9e2ee8
10289168
0x9e2eec
0
```

Why do `*(sa + i)` and  `*(h.data().data() + i)`  print different values?

---

`sa + i` and `&*(h.data().data() + i)` prints the same memory address, why I can not get the correct data just use this memory address (`sa + i`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hello::data()` is returning a `vector` **by value**, which means it will return a temporary *copy* of `hello::v`, which will allocate its own `int` array and copy the values from `v`.

When calling `h.data()`, that *temporary* `vector` will be destroyed when it goes out of scope at the end of the full statement that called `h.data()`.

So, in your 1st loop:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    std::cout << &*(h.data().data() + i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(h.data().data() + i) << std::endl;
}
```

This is perfectly valid code, as the *temporary* `vector` returned by each call to `h.data()` will not be destroyed until after its inner data has been printed.

However, in your 2nd loop:

```cpp
int *sa = h.data().data();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    std::cout << sa + i << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(sa + i) << std::endl;
}
```

In the statement that is calling `h.data()`:

```cpp
int *sa = h.data().data();
```

The *temporary* `vector` gets destroyed when it goes out of scope at the end of the statement, leaving `sa` to be a **dangling pointer to freed memory**, thus any use of `sa` inside the loop is **undefined behavior**.

`sa + i` and `h.data().data() + i` *may* point at the same memory address, but only if this last call to `h.data()` *happens* to create a new `vector` that reuses the same memory block that the temporary `vector`s in the 1st loop used, but **that is not a guarantee**.  In any case, `sa` is pointing at **freed memory**, so it doesn't matter if the memory block was reused or not, the `vector` that owned that memory block is destroyed, freeing the memory, before the 2nd loop is entered.  That is why you can't access the data, even if the memory addresses were the same.

To fix this issue, you need to change `hello::data()` to return a **reference** to `hello::v` instead, then no *copy* will be created, eg:

```cpp
class hello
{
public:
    std::vector<int>& data() // <-- note the &
    {
        return v;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
};
```

Thus each call to `h.data().data()` will return a valid pointer to `v`'s internal data, thus `sa` will not be a dangling pointer anymore.

Alternatively, have `hello::data()` return a pointer to `v`'s data, rather than returning (a reference to) `v` itself, eg:

```cpp
class hello
{
public:
    int* data()
    {
        return v.data();
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
};

...

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    std::cout << &*(h.data() + i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(h.data() + i) << std::endl;
}

...

int *sa = h.data();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    std::cout << sa + i << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(sa + i) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: const reference ? :-)

Comment: Ideally yes, in this particular example, but then `int *sa` will have to be changed to `const int *sa` to match. Plus, maybe the OP wants mutable access to `v`, we don't know how `hello` is intended to be used outside of this example

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But `sa + i` and `h.data().data() + i` print the same memory address, why I can not get the correct data just use this memory address (`sa + i` )

Answer (score 1):

You returned a temporary copy of your vector. After the statement it is part of it is destroyed. If you wanted to keep it around you need to assign it to another vector.

So, you made a pointer to a temporary value which got erased. It no longer exists, and you're trying to point to pieces of its corpse.